# Find next and previous basename in same foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, glob

```
$files = glob("../../users/$username/posts/*");
foreach( $files as $eachfile )
{
    echo basename($eachfile); //this is current basename
    echo "?"; //previous basename how will be?
    echo "?"; //next basename how will be?
}
```

How I can echo the next and the previous basename of the loop, on the same loop, i mean without the php do again the foreach as you can see in the example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could do something like:

```
$files = glob("../../users/$username/posts/*");
for($i = 1; $i < count($files) - 1;$i++)
{
    echo basename($files[$i]); //this is current basename
    echo basename($files[$i - 1]);
    echo basename($files[$i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: its very good, but ksort, rsort its not working, i for reason i dont know why, its seems to "eating" not show some files.

Comment: There was no mention of ksort and rsort in your question. If there is more to this question, please update it. Or if there is an answer here to your question, accept it and create another question with your rsort and ksort problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Simplify first

To get the loop right, it could be easier to see the three values as looking back only, not ahead:
Instead of "need the previous and next basename", you can simplify the problem as "need the previous two basenames".

### Save old values

Now, you can save the previous two basenames in two variables.

The current basename can be saved at the end of the loop as the previous one for the next loop.
The previous basename will be the second previous one in next iteration.

### Rename to make next part easier

The simplification was useful for this part, but it may be easier for the later parts of the algorithm to have previous and next basename. So, if that helps, you could now rename the variables `curent`, `previous` and `previous2` to `next`, `curent`, and `previous`.

In pseudocode (I don't know php):

```
prev = files[0]
curr = files[1]
next = files[2]

for (i = 2...files.length) {
    next = files[i]

    echo prev
    echo curr
    echo next

    prev = curr
    curr = next
}
```

Comment: You can leave out the action part of the loop the first two times. For this, a `for` loop would be better. But with a `for` loop, you can also save the first two before the loop, and stat at 2.

Comment: the for loop (like the user bellow) its not display some data, i will try to fix it, that is the reason i wait, i can not do it with 2 previous basenames becouse i need also also the first 2 data.

Comment: For the first two, some of the values are just not available, there is no way around that, right?

Comment: i can make a an other and an other foreach above the foreach for the first and second values i think.